# To be + continuous

Tags: grammaticality

I'm pretty much confused about the following sentence:

*1. She thinks this is an interesting time to be adding Apple to her portfolio.*

*2. I want to be reading the book*

How can I break up the above sentences by using "that" ?

Comment: It's a typo. I'll fix it. Can you tell me how to break up the sentences? I'm confused about that.

Comment: Both sentences sound rather odd. I'd be happier with << 1'. _She thinks this is a good time to be adding Apple to one's portfolio._ >> The 'to be V-ing' usage doesn't sit well in many sentences. How does (2) work? Aren't 'I want to read the book' / 'I want to start reading the book' / 'I want to get into the book' far more natural-sounding?

Comment: (2) only makes sense if you are doing something else but would much rather be reading. You can't use _that_ in it.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. It seems to be confusing to me. I found it while reading an article. Should I use this type of English?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the existing sentences. What are you trying to accomplish (and why) by modifying them with the addition of *that*? Why do you need to break them up?

Comment: @JasonBassford I'm learning advance one by breaking up the sentence. For example:  I'm glad to have found this beautiful house.  I can break this sentence : I'm glad that I've found this beautiful house.  You got my point. CanI break up the above sentences?

Answer (score 1):

1. She thinks THAT this is an interesting time...

Number 2 -- I can't see how to use THAT.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. It seems to be confusing to me. I found it while reading an article. Should I use this type of English?

Answer (score 1):

A "that" clause is a finite clause (containing a finite verb), introduced by the word *that*, that stands as a component in a larger sentence, often as the object of a verb of thinking or sensing, but sometimes in other contexts. The word "that" can often be omitted.

A "to"-infinitive clause is a non-finite clause where the verb in base form is preceded by "to". It also stands as a component in a larger sentence, and is often the object of a verb. It does not take the complementiser "that".

*Think* is one of the many verbs that can take a "that" clause as its object: so your first example contains a "that" clause without its "that", and you may restore it after *thinks*. You can tell this because the verb is in the finite form *is*.

*Want* does not usually take a "that" clause, but a "to"-infinitive clause. This is the case here, so there is no "that" to restore in your second sentence. You can tell this because the verb is in the base form *be*.

Note that neither meaning nor a rule will tell you which kind of clause a given verb can take: *wish* (whose meaning is very close to *want*) can take either of the two kinds of clause I have described. This is a property of individual verbs that just has to  be learnt.